# SOAP UI - How to determine time taken between steps

Tags: groovy, soapui

I just want to know what will be the best way to determine time taken between test steps and log an overall average time within free version of SOAP UI? I have a test which has a 2 request steps, lets say request step 1 is step 3 and request step 2 is step 5 in the test case. I am performing a load test so I'm iterating through the test multiple times but want to know the average time taken between request step 1 and until it reaches request step 2 after the whole test has finished.

Any ideas on best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the [Date Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) from request's response.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some groovy script in the steps to write timestamps in a file...